# Input .tex in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I'm using Rmarkdown/Bookdown to write a paper/PDF document, which is an amazing tool @Yihui, thanks! Now I'm trying to include a table I have already put in LaTeX into the document by reading in this external .tex file. However, when knitting in RStudio with a `\include{some-file.tex}` or `input{some-file.tex}` in the body of the .Rmd outside of a chunk a `LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.` is produced and the process stopped. I haven't found a way how to directly input through knit or otherwise into a chunk as well.

I found this question here: [Rmarkdown v2, embed Latex document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638759/rmarkdown-v2-embed-latex-document), although while the question is similar, there is no answer which would reflect how to input/include .tex-files into an .Rmd.

Why would I want this? Sometimes LaTeX tables offer more layout options than building directly in R, like for tables only with text rather than R-computed numbers. Also, when running models on a cluster, exporting results directly into .tex ready for compilation saves a lot of computation compared to have to open all these heavy .RData files just for getting the results into a PDF. Similarly, having sometimes multiple types of reports with different audiences, having the full R code in one main .Rmd file and integrating only the necessary results in other files reduces complexity by not having to redo all steps in each file newly. This way, I can keep one report with the full picture and do not have to check if I included every little change in various documents simultaneously.

So finally the question is how to get prepared .tex-Files into a .Rmd-document?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Whats the content of `some-file.tex`? Seems like there is one more more commands that should only be used inside the preamble.

Comment: if `somefile.tex` starts with `\begin{document}` then it will produce the latex error you mentioned. Try removing the `\begin{document}, \end{document}`. Also see the [includes section of the documentation](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#includes)

Comment: Indeed, @MartinSchmelzer, there was an `\usepackage{}` added by the export function in front of the table, no other commands (like `\begin{document}`). Excluding this leads to a correct integration when using `\input{some-file.tex}`, but with `\include{some-file.tex}` basically nothing shows up. 

Thanks for the help, seems an obvious mistake now...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a latex code in bookdown, you just need to add this to your `_output.yml` file:

```
bookdown::pdf_book:
    keep_tex: yes
```

[image: bookdown pdf keep tex]
and then the only thing you need is to copy your tex code into one of the `.rmd` files like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
name & age & gender &  &  \\
Reza & 25  & M      &  &  \\
John & 42  & M      &  &  \\
Rose & 21  & F      &  & 
\end{tabular}
```

> I'm not familiar with tex & latex, and just use a site to generate this table. You don't need to use `\begin{table}[]` and `end{table}`

this is `index.rmd`:
[image: index.rmd]
then, on the build pane click on drop menu and click on `bookdown::pdf_book`
and this is pdf file:[image: pdf file]

If this trick doesn't help you, I need more information.
This work only for pdf output.